Using the here-library not working after change of dropbox location
After updating my mac and dropbox, I am having big trouble setting the base project dir. I used to have a pointer set to the project folder and then I could use setwd(here("proj X")) both on my home mac and my office computer.
I´ve tried to remove all .here files in the library recursion back to my user, except for the project folder. I´ve tried different locations with touch .here from terminal to no avail. I´ve unistalled and reinstalled after setwd to the project folder. Then here() is ok until I restart the session whereafter here points to my ~directory and I have to write out setwd(here("Library","CloudStorage","Dropbox","Projfolder","proj X")) to access my data. Obviously this will also be different on my windows machine at work. Any idea how this can be helped?

and when i try to render the quarto file, here() points correctly to my project. very odd

Is there a reason why you don't work with project files, you might never use setwd() again. setwd(here()) is a strange idiom.

when (and in what directory) do you run library(here)?  I see "here() starts at /home/..." output immediately after running library(here). what's getwd()? does your project root have .git in list.files(all.files=T)

You can check the output of dr_here() [0] to help you debug what's going wrong, especially the line

Initial working directory: /path/here/loaded/from

I suspect library(here) is called before your R session's working directory is at or within the project root directory (with a .here file). The here package uses .onLoad to run do_refresh_here on wherever the R session currently is (".") when library(here) is first called.
If something upstream out of your control is loading here too early, you can manually reload the package once your session is configured (you R console is within the project folder) like
detach("package:here", unload=TRUE)
library(here)


[0] example dr_here output
dr_here()
here() starts at /home/foranw/src/mytestproject.
- This directory contains a directory ".git"
- Initial working directory: /home/foranw/src/mytestproject/blah
- Current working directory: /tmp


